# Android USB Programing

Tags: android, usb

I want to do PC Sync, between pc and android mobile. So I need some USB cable Programming APIs. Like request for connection and response. And also i want to know what is dun_service.

Thanks
Laxman Dodda

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible. The kernel doesn't provide direct access to the USB. It supports only ADB's driver (for debugging) and USB gadget mode for mounting file systems to the attached machine (like the SD card)

Comment: Technically you can use USB debugging for your own purposes. See PDA Net.

Comment: you can't trust it though always being there on all models or being enabled on every device. a few OEM and carriers have jailed their phones to disable dev mode.

Comment: It wasn't possible in 2010.  Is this possible now with newer versions of Android?